# Jquery Serialize form data returns error

Tags: jquery, forms, serialization

I'm trying to use jquery to send form data to another PHP page.

This is the code I have :

```
var datastring = $("#form1").serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "save.php",
                data: datastring,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data)
                },
                error: function(data) {
                    alert('error handing here');
                    console.log(data)
                }
            });
```

When I run this I get an alert 'error handing here' and output logged to my console.

Save just contains:

```
<?php
    ECHO "HELLO";
?>
```

The data logged on the console is :

`Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "HELLO", status: 200, statusText: "OK"}`

Can anyone advise why this isn't working.. and when it does how do I read the data submitted to save.php ?

Thanks

Comment: You're requesting a JSON response, but `HELLO` is not valid JSON. Therefore, jQuery's internal parsing operation fails, and you receive an error.

Comment: You aren't returning formated JSON string from your PHP script, that's why. So to test it, return JSON or remove `datatype` option for ajax request

Comment: `dataType: 'text'` will fix this, or use `json_encode()` in your PHP to actually return a JSON response.

Comment: Thanks - stupid mistake..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't response `JSON` in your script, it is plain text. So you should change your `dataType` to `html` or `text`:

```
dataType: "html",
```

Or change your php script to a json response:

```
echo json_encode(array("text" => "HELLO"));
```